# Last_value over partition by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that contains column Fruit,Date,Price,Flag.

I use 
First_value(Price) over (partition by  Fruit order by Fruit, Date) to generate Column Price First

last_value(Price) over (partition by  Fruit order by Fruit,Date rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) to generate Column Price Last

```
Fruit   Date       Price    Flag    Price first   Price Last
Apple   6/1/2015    1.4     Yes       1.4           1.9
Apple   6/2/2015    1.5     Yes       1.4           1.9
Apple   6/3/2015    2.5     Yes       1.4           1.9
Apple   6/4/2015    3       Yes       1.4           1.9
Apple   6/5/2015    1.7     Yes       1.4           1.9 
Apple   6/6/2015    1.9     No        1.4           1.9
```

But I need another column "Price Last Flag Yes"  to give me the last updated price for fruit Apple that don't have flag No,In this case, it should be the price at 6/5/2015

```
Fruit   Date       Price    Flag    Price first  Price Last  Price Last Flag Yes
Apple   6/1/2015    1.4     Yes       1.4           1.9        1.7
Apple   6/2/2015    1.5     Yes       1.4           1.9        1.7
Apple   6/3/2015    2.5     Yes       1.4           1.9        1.7
Apple   6/4/2015    3       Yes       1.4           1.9        1.7
Apple   6/5/2015    1.7     Yes       1.4           1.9        1.7 
Apple   6/6/2015    1.9     No        1.4           1.9        1.7
```

I don't know how to query the condition that filters out the Flag "no" within the functions. I don't want to go through subqueries. It is possible to add conditions and filters within the function? Thanks

I don't want to use where clause because then I need to use subquery. I also tried last_value(case when Flag = 'Yes' then Price end) over (partition by fruit order by Fruit,date), it doesn't work either. For some reason it messes the data and some rows are empty.

Comment: add a `where` clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the `IGNORE NULLS` option:

```
last_value(case when Flag = 'Yes' then Price end ignore nulls) 
over (partition by Fruit order by Date ...
```

Btw, `partition by Fruit, Date order by Fruit,Date` will not work, it's `partition by Fruit order by Date` instead

Comment: yeah thanks! that's what I need ---- ignore nulls. That way it works as a filter.