# Replace null values with value in group

Tags: sql

I have table with three columns: contractID, customergroup, customerID. Some data for customerID is missing, and I need to find a way to replace those NULL values with customerID in corresponding customergroup. Also, if no customerID is found for the customergroup, then leave cell as blank.

Example:

| contractID | customergroup | customerID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20135 | B2021 | 5521 |
| 20136 | B2021 | NULL |
| 20137 | B2022 | NULL |
| 20138 | B2022 | 5523 |
| 20139 | B2022 | 5523 |
| 20140 | B2023 | NULL |

Expected:

| contractID | customergroup | customerID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20135 | B2021 | 5521 |
| 20136 | B2021 | 5521 |
| 20137 | B2022 | 5523 |
| 20138 | B2022 | 5523 |
| 20139 | B2022 | 5523 |
| 20140 | B2023 |  |

Comment: this is called "forward-filling" and you can achieve it using a last_value function, you can find help with the syntax here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31733070/last-value-over-partition-by

Comment: You should consider, if possible, properly normalising your data - storing `CustomerID` here probably means the data is denormalised since it can allow for contradictory information.

Comment: I agree with Stu. It looks like the customergroup column should be in the customer table instead and get removed from the contract table. Don't write queries to circumvent database flaws. Fix the database instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a sub-query to fill the missing ids as the following:

```
SELECT contractID, customergroup,
       CASE WHEN customerID IS NULL THEN
       COALESCE((SELECT customerID FROM table_name D 
       WHERE D.customergroup = T.customergroup AND 
       D.customerID IS NOT NULL 
       LIMIT 1), '')
       ELSE customerID 
       END AS customerID
FROM table_name T
ORDER BY contractID
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/HVX_miyh) on MySQL.

Answer (score -4):

---

Select contractID , customergroup, ISNULL(customerID, ' ') as customerID
From tablename

---

In the blank space ' ' you can enter the value you want

Comment: How would this transport customer ID *5521* to contract 20136?